# TreeView option to select and de-select by clicking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been looking for a treeView widget option where I can select only a single row at a time by clicking it and then de-select it by clicking on it again. I found how to make it so that you can select only one row at a time, but I was unable to find an option that allowed u to click the selected row to de-select it.

Does anyone know how this can be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom binding to deselect the item if it's currently selected.  If your binding returns the string `break`, it will stop event propagation and thus prevent the default behavior for double-click.

```
...
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(...)
self.tree.bind("<1>", self.on_click)
...
def on_click(self, event):
    selection = self.tree.selection()
    item = self.tree.select_row(event.y)
    if item in selection:
        self.tree.selection_remove(item)
        return "break"
```

Comment: I was going to ask about a significance of returning `break` at the end, but found it out myself [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) (it stops event propagation).

Answer (score 0):

[Unfortunately](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/blt/html/hierbox.html), the only built-in pattern to toggle the selection state of a treeview item is by selecting a different item but you can do a hack of your own.